# Get SQL Table Info

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get SQL table information from a linked server? I have a table called "Address" and it is on a remote server which is linked under "Server Objects"->"Linked Servers". I need to know the information about the table. I tried exec sp_help 'Address' 
 but it doesnt work with remote servers.

Comment: Please add some more details - DBMS information and what exactly you need to know about the table

Comment: Table structure, Created Date and Primary Key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views from a linked server using the fully qualified domain name.  So, data types and columns, for example, would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  MYLINKEDSERVER.MYDATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Address'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenQuery with system tables on the remote database. Here is a basic example, but you build it out to query other system tables to get dependencies etc.

```
Select  *
From    OpenQuery([TargetServer],  'Select  ss.name As SchemaName,
                                            so.name As OjbectName,
                                            sc.name As ColumnName,
                                            st.name As ColumnDataType
                                    From    [TargetDatabase].sys.sysobjects so
                                    Join    [TargetDatabase].sys.syscolumns sc
                                            On  so.id = sc.id
                                    Join    [TargetDatabase].sys.schemas ss
                                            On  so.uid = ss.Schema_ID
                                    Join    [TargetDatabase].sys.types st
                                            On  sc.xtype = st.system_type_id
                                    Where   so.name = ''TableName''')
```